# Get the value of a field Mongodb in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, field

I want to get the value of a field while im looping through a collection, and if that field equals to "true", create another field with updateOne and $set.
I'm using this code for looping:

```
var userCollection = db.getCollection('users');
var bulkOp = userCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
userCollection.find().forEach(function (doc) {
  bulkOp.find(doc).updateOne({
    '$set': {
      'gender': "male"
    }
  });
  count++;
  if (count % 100 === 0) {
    bulkOp.execute();
    bulkOp = userCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  }
});
if (count > 0) {
  bulkOp.execute();
}
```

my collection looks like this:

```
[{
name: "Roy",
age: 30,
is_male: true,
is_female: false
```

},
  {
    name: "Lena",
    age: 29,
    is_male: false,
    is_female: true
  }
]

Now I want to state a condition that if doc.is_male = false than set gender:"female".
Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do that via update.

```js
db.collection.update(query,condition)
```

In this case:

```
db.collection.update({"is_male":false},{$set:{"gender":"female"}})
```

Pleas excuse any typos, I have, but let me know if that doesn't work for you or if there is a condition I'm over looking.  (mongo will do the magic :))

Comment: It did work with a separate coding, I was trying to set these conditions inside the loop but It didn't work,Thank you for replying!

Comment: NP...the reason you can't set them in the loop is because setting each one is an Async operation.  you could in theory do that when an async iterator perhaps, but as you can see this is much easier approach and best to use the tool as intended by designers.